# Twitter tweet event not fired in IE

Tags: twitter

I don't see any luck on twitter discussions about there tweet event. I think many are experiencing about the tweet event in twitter where it is not being fired in IE. See the code below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div>
  <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
     data-url="http://www.testsite.com"
     data-text="hello world @"
    data-count="none">Tweet</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
   twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
     alert("Post successful");    
   });
  });
</script>
</body>
```

This script works fine on other browsers except IE. Posting to twitter is successful. There's no javascript error.

Anyone has an idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Related Twitter issue tracker tickets: https://dev.twitter.com/issues/88, https://dev.twitter.com/issues/409. However, tiny tips first is giving doesn't help me as well.